# How to "convert" a plugin to a gem a make it "private"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, rubygems

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2. I have implemented a `Something` plugin (it is almost a gem, but is not a gem) and all related files are in the `lib/something` directory.

1. What steps should I accomplish to "convert" the `Something` plugin to a Ruby gem?
2. How to use the new implemented `Something` gem in my application without to make it public (that is, without put that on a public server)?

Answer (score 2):

1. http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/
2. Previous link covers that as well - gem install something-1.2.3.gem

Comment: Could you go into a bit more detail on this answer?  It seems like it's a link-only answer...

Comment: That link got nice step-by-step tutorial how to create your own gem. Of course, I can copypaste it for you ;)

Comment: Copy-paste wouldn't feel right either.  I did follow the link and it does contain a lot of valuable information in it, though.

Comment: in short - you'll need to create simple gem as described there and move files from lib/something to gem's lib.